# Connect to remote mysql host from network with proxy

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-12.04

- Ubuntu machine in internet zone with proxy server.
- And i want to connect to remote mysql server `mysql -u userName -p -h hostname`.
- And also i have java application that connect to that remote mysql host using hibernate ORM.
- And i can't connect with the server.

**Edit** 
I dont want to use mysql proxy but my database exists on remote server but my local machine have connection to the internet throw web proxy so i can't connect to remote db server.
And when i try connect from machine that has direct access to the internet **That Work Perfectly**

- Trials.

1-System -> Preferences -> Network Proxy.

2- export http_proxy = http:userName:password@proxyserver:port

but that doesn't work.
and help will be appreciated..

**Update:**

```
    static {
    // SOCKS Proxy
    System.setProperty("proxySet", "true");
    System.setProperty("socksProxyHost", "proxy-host");
    System.setProperty("socksProxyPort", "proxy-port");
    System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "proxy-host");
    System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "proxy-port");
    System.setProperty("java.net.socks.username", "username");
    System.setProperty("java.net.socks.password", "password");
    Authenticator.setDefault(new ProxyAuthenticator("username", "password"));
```

// **Open Web Site Work good**

```
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://www.kooora.com/");
        URLConnection con = url.openConnection();

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                con.getInputStream()));

        // Read it ...
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException iOException) {
        iOException.printStackTrace();
    }
```

// **But open mysql connection throw exception**

```
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        return DriverManager.getConnection(getDBUrl(), USERNAME, PASSWORD);
```

**`com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.`**

Comment: Why would you want a proxy to the database at all? A database connection is not a stateless protocol like HTTP, so a HTTP proxy will be of no use. You need either a SOCKS proxy, or maybe the MySQL Proxy (http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql-proxy/) can be of help.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking or why you would need to use a proxy server to access the remote MySQL server.  Is the MySQL server accessible from the Internet but the machine you are trying to connect from doesn't have access to the Internet?  How does the Java application factor into your question?  Is it working or is this what you are trying to get working.  Please edit your question to provide more detail.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Kindly see my question updates

Comment: @ErnestV kindly see question updates, help me which proxy can be work with mysql database connection.

Comment: What you see here a simple connection problem - the app server is not able to communicate with the database server. I suppose that it can connect but not talk to it, i.e. the TCP connection works, but no packets get transmitted. You should check your network settings like routing (or have them checked) - I don't think a proxy would change much here.